# Is this one-step ahead prediction? Can I turn it into multistep prediction?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, time-series, statsmodels

I have "inherited" this code and I am not familiar with the SARIMAX model. The comments help to understand what is happening, but I do not understand the last line where the prediction is done.

The dataset has 1171 rows in total, splitted into 1000 training rows and 171 test rows. This translates to:

```
 Model.predict(1000, 1170, exog=exo_test, typ='levels')
```

I looked at the documentation for predict(). While the first parameter is the endog-parameter, the second should be the exog parameter. But when exog=exog_test, what is the 1170 supposed to mean? Also the documentation does not mention the 'typ' parameter.

What I do not understand:

1. Is this a one-step-ahead prediction? Meaning that it takes true values, predicts the next step and then discards the prediction, takes the next true value in time to predict the next?

[1. a) Wouldn't the SARIMAX Model be needed to be fitted again/retrained if it is a one-step prediction? Shouldn't the last true values be used and thus after each one-step prediction retrained on the true values?]

2. Is this multistep prediction, meaning the predictions in t+2 is based on the prediction and not the true value in t+1?
3. As I am assuming that it is one-step prediction, is it possible to "easily" transform this into a multistep prediction?

Full code:

```
#load dataset
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col = 'date', parse_dates = True)

#split the closing price into train and test data
train = df.iloc[:1000,4]
test = df.iloc[1000:,4]

#select exogenous variables
exo = df.iloc[:,6:61]

#split exogenuous variables into train and test data
exo_train = exo.iloc[:1000]
exo_test = exo.iloc[1000:]

#run auto_arima to find the best configuration (I selected m=7 and D=1 by running seasonal_decompose and acf and pacf plots)
auto_arima(df['close'], exogenous=exo, m=7, trace=True, D=1).summary()

#set the best configuration from auto_arima for the SARIMAX model 
Model = SARIMAX(train, exog = exo_train, order=(1,0,2), seasonal_order = (0,1,1,7))

#train model
Model = Model.fit()

#get prediction
prediction = Model.predict(len(train), len(train)+len(test)-1, exog = exo_test, typ = 'levels')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple exercise will show that these are *dynamic* predictions and so are multi-step (that is, the first is 1-step, then the 2nd is is 2-step, and so on).

```py
#generate dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ArmaProcess, SARIMAX
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(20220308)

ap = ArmaProcess.from_coeffs([1.8, -0.9])
sample = ap.generate_sample(1170)

#split the closing price into train and test data
train = sample[:1000]
test = sample[1000:]

#select exogenous variables
exo = np.random.standard_normal((1170, 2))

#split exogenuous variables into train and test data
exo_train = exo[:1000]
exo_test = exo[1000:]

#set the best configuration from auto_arima for the SARIMAX model 
model = SARIMAX(train, exog = exo_train, order=(2,0,0), trend="c")

#train model
res = model.fit()

#get prediction
prediction = res.predict(len(train), len(train)+len(test)-1, exog = exo_test, typ = 'levels')

x = np.arange(len(prediction))
plt.plot(x,test, x, prediction)
plt.show()
```

which produces

[image: dynamic prediction from SARIMAX]

You can tell it is a multi-step since this model is stationary (an AR(2)) and the long-run forecast reverts to the unconditional mean.

Comment: Then I have a follow up question: What is the prediction in lets say timestep 100 based on? Is it based on the predicted value in timestep 99 and the exogenous factors that are provided in timestep 99? The thing is this model performs extremely well and can predict the next 171 days of a cryptocurrency which is basically impossible if this was truly a multistep prediction. And again: Wouldn't I need to refit the model in timestep 99 on the true values to predict timestep 100?

Comment: You should be predicting the return (first difference of log prices) on the crypto, not the level.  The level likely has random-walk-like features and so may appear to be highly predictable when you cannot predict the return.

Comment: I predict the daily return (as percent change which is almost the same as the log return) and go long when it predicts that difference to today is positive and go short when it predicts a negative difference to today. It often does not hit the exact change but it is highly accurate in predicting if its going up or down. It is so accurate that it simply is too good to be true especially considering that it is multistep. Could you maybe explain once more in simple words what the prediction in a timestep is based on? Is it based on the previous prediction + the previous exogenous factors?

Comment: Suppose you had a simple AR(1) with 1 exog variable, y(t) = a + b y(t-1) + c*x(t).  This is a basic SARIMAX model. Your 1-step prediction is then E[y(t+1)] = a + b y(t) + c * x(t+1). Your 2-step is E[y(t+2)] = a + b E[y(t+1)] + c * x(t+2), and your h-step is E[y(t+h)] = a + b E[y(t+h-1)] + c * x(t+h).  One place where you could be fooling yourself is if the x-variables are not actually know at time t.  The exog you use in a multi-step forecast should be multi-step forecasts of the x-variables themselves, not the actual.  The only exception is when the x are determinstic functions of time.

Comment: okay, thank you for your help! I think I start to understand it now! The problem is probably, that I have some kind of mix here: the exog data is given for the test data, but at t0 it is not known yet and can only be calculated for every single step. so there is a flaw in the approach. Hence, my thought of refitting after each step is in way valid as I could turn this flawed multistep into a single step predictor. Thanks again for you help and your insights! Very much appreciated!